# Removing no such file command from OSX terminal startup

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, startup

Whenever I start a new Terminal session, the window opens up with a command:

```
'-bash: cd: /Users/yourusername/Library/lejos_nxj: No such file or directory'.
```

I want to remove that line from coming up on the prompt, so I deleted the Terminal plist file and sent hard resets, but nothing has worked for me so far.

Is there anything I haven't tried yet?

Comment: When you open a terminal in OS X, it tries to execute the following files in order: `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bashrc`, `/Users/jano/.profile` (jano is my username). Open each of them and look for `nxj` which is the prefix for all NXJ commands and variables.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably got something in your ~/.profile, which is automatically executed when you open a Terminal.

If you did not set anything in there, do

```
rm ~/.profile
```

in a Terminal and this should disappear.

If you think that something important may be in there, do

```
open -a TextEdit ~/.profile
```

(or change TextEdit to your preferred editor) to view and edit the file.

Comment: I wouldn't do that, as other programs can put things in that file.  I'd search through `~/.profile` first.

Comment: For reference, the only program I ever encountered that added something important to `~/.profile` was MacPorts.

Comment: Thanks! I found the culprit at /.bash_profile. Deleting that fixed up my Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

That line is probably in either your `~/.bashrc` file or your `~/.profile` file.  I would check those two files first (and they are both hidden because of the period initial character).

Edit: I just checked my OS X system, and I don't have `~/.bashrc` (but you may).

Answer (score 0):

You could try a terminal replacement (Just recently read about this one, [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home)) it might 
resolve your problem by using its own default startup settings.

If it is anything like Linux the `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` are used when you open your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that most people assume it is in some init file but its not clear which are included.  Once your shell does come up (ignore errors) -try this:

```
script
bash -l -x
exit
exit
```

Now you should have a file called `typescript` which will have debug info showing most if not all of what the shell has executed when coming up in login mode.  You could for instance do `grep source typescript` to see which files were involved OR you could find refrences to nxj etc.

p.s. I assume your clearing of the plist would clear the preferences, but wouldn't hurt to see if the relevant command is in 'Terminal-> Presences->Settings->Shell->Run Command' for any of the terminal window presets